# loggin : session or cookie (with rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

if I use signed cookie to staure a "session_token" with 32 randomed characters, why continue to use session?

exemple:

```
def current_user
  return nil unless authentication_token = cookies.signed[:authentication_token]
  @_current_user ||= User.find_by_authentication_token(authentication_token)
end


def current_user=(user)
  return cookies.delete(:authentication_token) if user.nil?
  cookies.signed.permanent[:authentication_token] = user.authentication_token
end
```

**what's the advantages to use session?**

Comment: Depends on your use-case , if you want to store stats related to your users then session comes in handy . Also it's way secure compared to other method , there are certain situations when the user has to login from different browsers when it's advantageous to use sessions .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder sessions aren't shared between browsers, so I don't understand what you said.

Comment: Sorry i meant different tabs of same browser

Comment: @CaffeineCoder the permanant signed cookie are present too, like session, in others tabs.

Comment: The advantage to the database is that session data cannot be tampered with on the client side and that you can store a larger amount of data than you would with cookies

Comment: Cookies are restricted to 4 kb in size

Comment: @CaffeineCoder session are strored in cookie, so there are limited at 4ko too.

Comment: Session data *can* be stored just in a cookie, but more commonly the session data is stored in the database (or redis etc - something at the server side, anyway), and the cookie just stores an id or other key which can be used to retrieve the appropriate session record from the db.  Pseudorandom keys are preferred to id as they are harder to guess (thus making it harder to hijack someone else's session data)